# Is the whole debate Kuhn-Popper contained in "Criticism and Growth of Knowledge"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, popper, kuhn

In the *Preface* of I.Lakatos and A.Musgrave's *Criticism and Growth of Knowledge*, I read that the book is the fourth volume of the Acts of the International Congress of Philosophy of Science (London, 1965).

In the Congress Kuhn and Popper discussed about progress in science and normal science.
In the mentioned book there are Popper and Kuhn's essays. Are there other volumes of the mentioned Congress Acts which contain essays about that Kuhn-Popper debate or *Criticism and Growth of Knowledge* is the only one?

Answer (score 2):

I think so.

See the other volumes :

- Imre Lakatos & Alan Musgrave (editors), [Problems in the Philosophy of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books/about/Problems_in_the_Philosophy_of_Mathematic.html?id=4VwgAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), North Holland (1967)
- Imre Lakatos & Alan Musgrave (editors), [Problems in the philosophy of science](https://www.amazon.it/Philosophy-Proceedings-Foundations-Mathematics-North-Holland/dp/B0050K8BH4), North Holland (1968)
- Imre Lakatos (editor), [The problem of inductive logic](https://books.google.it/books/about/The_Problem_of_Inductive_Logic.html?id=rLstAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), North Holland (1968).

On the debate, you can see :

- Stefano Gattei, [Thomas Kuhn's Linguistic Turn and the Legacy of Logical Empiricism](https://books.google.it/books?id=4JmoDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Ashgate (2008);
- Joseph Agassi, [Popper and His Popular Critics : Thomas Kuhn, Paul Feyerabend, and Imre Lakatos](https://books.google.it/books?id=clglBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2014).